# Displaying items in a list or array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop

I have troubles trying to display a list of items/objects in a array.

What I'm doing is I'm adding students with a name, surname, age, and marks for subjects (Properties) to an array. If I added 4 students in this manner to the list I want to display all the students with their properties again in the richTextBox when the Display button is clicked.

How do I go about it in the "displayAll_Click" function?? Must I use a for loop of some sort?? Any help will be appreciated.

I have the following code:

### In this fucntion I'm adding the student into the array:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create new student and assign name etc provided by user
        Student _Student = new Student();
        _Student.Name = txtName.Text;
        _Student.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
        _Student.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
        _Student.ITMark = Convert.ToInt32(txtIT.Text);
        _Student.MathMark = Convert.ToInt32(txtMath.Text);
        _Student.EngMark = Convert.ToInt32(txtEng.Text);

        MessageBox.Show("Student added.");

        // Increase counter and display how many students added so far
        CountStudents++;

        Average = Convert.ToInt32(txtIT.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtMath.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtEng.Text);
        _Student.AverageMark = Average / 3;

        //Display Student's properties in the richBox
        richTextBox1.Text = ("Student: " + Convert.ToString(CountStudents) +
                             "\nName: " + _Student.Name +
                            "\nSurname: " + _Student.Surname +
                             "\nAge: " + _Student.Age +
                             "\nStudent Average: " + Convert.ToString(_Student.AverageMark));

        //Add the newly added student to the ClassList array
        ClassList[CountStudents - 1] = _Student;

        //Clear the list after student is added
        txtAge.Clear();
        txtName.Clear();
        txtSurname.Clear();
        txtIT.Value = 0;
        txtMath.Value = 0;
        txtEng.Value = 0;
        txtName.Focus();
    }
```

### And in this function I want to display all the students that was added but how?

```
private void displayAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Student> _StudentList = new List<Student>();

        Student _Student = new Student();
        _Student.Name = txtName.Text;
        _Student.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
        _Student1.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
        _Student.ITMark = Convert.ToInt32(txtIT.Text);
        _Student.MathMark = Convert.ToInt32(txtMath.Text);
        _Student.EngMark = Convert.ToInt32(txtEng.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < _StudentList; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = ("Student: " + Convert.ToString(CountStudents) +
                             "\nName: " + _Student.Name +
                            "\nSurname: " + _Student.Surname +
                             "\nAge: " + _Student.Age +
                             "\nStudent Average: " + Convert.ToString(_Student.AverageMark));
            i++;
        }
        //Displaying all the students
        MessageBox.Show("Display all students.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning new text to richtextbox every time:

Use

```
richTextBox1.Text +=
```

instead of just

```
richTextBox1.Text =
```

Complete Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _StudentList; i++)
{
    Student currentStudent = ClassList[i];    //get student from array
    richTextBox1.Text += ("Student: " + Convert.ToString(CountStudents) +
                         "\nName: " + currentStudent .Name +
                         "\nSurname: " + currentStudent .Surname +
                         "\nAge: " + currentStudent .Age +
                         "\nStudent Average: " + Convert.ToString(currentStudent .AverageMark));
            i++;    //you don't need to do it, let the loop handle it
}
```

It'll append the new string into it without removing the previous.

Comment: Well its working sort of, but its only displaying the last item in the array and not all of them??

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems. Actually you are not adding srudents anywhere. You just show them. You need to create a global `List` where you have to add students in method `btnAdd_Click`, and then iterate through that list in method `displayAll_Click`.

Comment: I added it to the array though? Can't I access it trhough the array in some sort of way by looping through the array?

Comment: Yes you can access it from array as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
foreach(var student in _StudentList)
{
   richTextBox1.Text += ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your textbox each run, along with several other errors.  I'd use a StringBuilder and a `foreach` loop

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (var student in _StudentList)
 {
      sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + "Name: " + student.Name);
      sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + "Surname: " + student.Surname);
      sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + "Age: " + student.Age);
      sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + "Student Average: " + student.AverageMark);
      sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
 }

 richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Also, your first line `"Student: " + Convert.ToString(CountStudents)` doesn't make much sense, `CountStudents` is the number of students, not a unique identifier for that particular student.

Answer (score 0):

your second function looks like one big copy&paste error.
you are creating an empty _StudentList which you then proceed to iterate (although you compare an int with a List in your for). then you are displaying the one student you just created from the form data.

try this:

```
private void displayAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < ClassList.Count; i++)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += ("Student: " + Convert.ToString(i) +
                         "\nName: " + ClassList[i].Name +
                        "\nSurname: " + ClassList[i].Surname +
                         "\nAge: " + ClassList[i].Age +
                         "\nStudent Average: " + Convert.ToString(ClassList[i].AverageMark));
    }
    //Displaying all the students
    MessageBox.Show("Display all students.");
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain it but it gives a weird error in Visual Studio 2008 and then highlights the whole richTextBox's function in yellow saying something like the object reference is not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: And the ClassList.Count will not work. Apperently the '<' cannot be applied to operands of type int or group method?

Comment: well i don't know he datatype of your classlist. unfortunately the different collections have very inconsistent count/length methods or properties. in this case, try `Count()`. the other error would depend on the complete source, i don't know where and when ypur classlist gets initialized.